# How to make invoking code to know nothing about the code being invoked

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost

Based on [Beyond the C++ Standard Library: An Introduction to Boost](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321133544), section *Using Boost.Bind with Boost.Function* on page 328, the author illustrates one of the way that we can decouple the calling code from underlying implementation code.

> When separating graphical user interfaces (GUIs) from details on how
>   to handle actions (events) from the user, callbacks of some sort are
>   almost always used. If this callback mechanism is based on function
>   pointers, it is hard to avoid severe limitations of the types that can
>   be used with the callback, which in turn increases the risk of adding
>   coupling between the presentation and the business logic. We can avoid
>   this altogether by using Boost.Function, and when combined with a
>   library that supports argument binding, we can supply the context to
>   invocations of functions with ease. This is one of the most common
>   uses of this libraryto separate knowledge of the business logic from
>   the presentation layer.

```
class tape_recorder {
public:
  void play() {
    std::cout << "Since my baby left me...\n";
  }

  void stop() {
    std::cout << "OK, taking a break\n";
  }

  void forward() {
    std::cout << "whizzz\n";
  }

  void rewind() {
    std::cout << "zzzihw\n";
  }

  void record(const std::string& sound) {
    std::cout << "Recorded: " << sound << '\n';
  }
};

typedef boost::function<void()> command;

tape_recorder tr;

command play(boost::bind(&tape_recorder::play,&tr));
command stop(boost::bind(&tape_recorder::stop,&tr));
command forward(boost::bind(&tape_recorder::stop,&tr));
command rewind(boost::bind(&tape_recorder::rewind,&tr));
std::string s="What a beautiful morning...";
command record = boost::bind(&tape_recorder::record,&tr,s));


// Invoked from some GUI control...
  if (play) {
    play.execute();
  }

  // Invoked from some scripting client...
  stop.execute();
```

> With Boost.Function and Boost.Bind, it is possible to achieve the
>   decoupling that makes it possible for the invoking code to know
>   nothing about the code being invoked. It's immensely useful to combine
>   these two libraries in this way.

**Question**> I understand how the above code works but I still feel confused how to decouple the calling code from the real implementation as what the author originally wants to archive. The calling code(i.e. all kinds of commands) still needs to know what the member functions of `tape_recorder`. So what the decoupling really mean here?

Comment: IMO "decoupling" means the consumer needs to understand the contract, not how the contract is fulfilled, e.g. that there is a "play" function which produces an expected result with no need to understand how that result is actually achieved.

Answer (score 1):

All he's saying is that the Boost library provides a mechanism for "callbacks"; and he gives an example of how you can use a specific class "tape recorder" with a set of general functions ("open", "play, "stop", etc).  You could conceivably write a *different* class (smart phone?) that might implement the *same* functions.

These links might help:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/BoostBindFunction.aspx

http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?action=browse&diff=1&id=Boost.Function,_Boost.Bind,_And_Member_Functions

Comment: Here I assume that `tape_recorder` is the implementation detail which the author wants to hide from the real user. The way how he can achieve that is through Boost.Function. In your answer, you indicate a different class. what is the purpose of this different class? act as a role of caller?

Comment: The provided links do not answer my questions and they are good resources for Boost.Function and Boost.Bind.